# How to recover the deleted table data from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

accidently the data from MySql databse table has been deleted, so kindly tell me any solution to recover it.

Comment: I'm positive that you can't do this without a backup.

Comment: If only I could vote up your reply more tvanfosson..

Comment: Pls clarify the situation? Was the table data (rows) deleted or the table itself dropped, also what kind of table was it, etc. If you have it backed up, you could restore it (but since you're here I'm guessing that's a no.) Mangled databases are nasty :( good luck...

Comment: While you find out your options (if any), you should shut down the MySQL server and possibly put the disk off-line.

Comment: @ satyrwilder table is not droped only its data(rows) are deleted, and i have no backup of it.

Comment: Then you can't restore it.

Comment: I am guessing you have been letting that disk spin since you asked too. You are probably SOL.

Comment: innoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: @powtac, table engine is MyISAM and row format is dynamic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879176/how-to-recover-mysql-db-from-myd-myi-frm-files

Answer (score 3):

No. You deleted the data, so it is gone.

Recover from your backups.

Answer (score 2):

As most answer suggests it's not possible to UN-DELETE **but there is a hope** which assumes you have binary logging enabled and retained for longer period. Longer enough to include all the DMLs for the database.

If your database was created recently, changes were made recently you can always use [mysqlbinlog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html) utility to get DML SQLs from binary log and recover back.

You might like to read the interesting use-case and [steps to recover dropped database or table in MySQL](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/restore-dropped-mysql-database-from-binary-logs).

So, unless you have backup or binary logging (with enough retention) it's not possible to recover the dropped database.

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible to recover deleted data.